# Mongoose populate in MEAN stack not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I've been reading the documentation as well as other SO questions, but I cant really find what I'm doing wrong, even when looking at questions with pretty much the same code as mine, the solutions proposed there arent working.

Relevant code:

User schema (authentication uses it):

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')

Schema = mongoose.Schema

UserSchema = new Schema(
  name:
    type: String
    required: true
  password:
    type: String
    required: true
  admin:
    type: Boolean
    default: false
  apiKey:
    type: String
    required: true
)

User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Report schema:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose')

Schema = mongoose.Schema

ReportSchema = new Schema(
  # ...
    votes: [{
    user:
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
      ref: 'User'
    text:
      type: String
      default: ''}]
# ...
)

Report = mongoose.model('Report', ReportSchema)

module.exports = Report
```

Updating a report with a vote (req.user comes from the authentication system):

```
  query =
    _id: req.params.id

  vote = req.body

  params =
    $push:
      votes:
        user: req.user._id
        text: vote.text or ''

  Report.findOneAndUpdate query, params, (err, result) ->
    return res.status(500).send(err) if err
    return res.status(404).end() unless result
    res.send result
```

Looking up a report:

```
# ...
if (req.params.id)
    Report.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).populate('votes.user').exec (err, report) ->
      return res.status(404).end() unless report
      res.send report
# ...
```

Test suite:

```
Report = mongoose.model "Report"
User = mongoose.model "User"

# ...
    it "add a vote with a blank comment", (done) ->
      Report.findOne title: 'test', (err, report) ->
          return done(err) if err
          request(app).put("#{apiUrl}/#{report._id}/vote").set("Authorization", "Bearer testKey").end (err, res) ->
            return done(err) if err
            expect(res.statusCode).toBe 200
            Report.findOne title: 'test', (err, report) ->
              console.log report
              expect(report.votes?.length).toBe 1
              expect(report.votes[0]?.text).toEqual ''
              expect(report.votes[0]?.user?.name).toEqual 'test'
              done()
```

What the objects look like logged in console:

Report (the user field in votes array should be populated):

```
{ _id: 5592d13e35c84be816000006,
  ...
  __v: 0,
  votes:
   [ { user: 5592d14235c84be816000015,
       _id: 5592d14335c84be816000017,
       text: '' } ],
  ... 
}
```

User:

```
{ _id: 5592d14235c84be816000015,
  apiKey: 'testKey',
  password: 'testPassword',
  name: 'test',
  __v: 0,
  admin: false }
```

If someone could help me out with some guidelines or point out the mistake, I'd be very thankful

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: I do not see the field 'title' which you are using in your query in your report schema but I'm assuming the field exists and the collection has a document with the title value set to test? In your test suite, log the report._id that you are sending in your request and check if it matches the one you expect it to be

Comment: @SasikanthBharadwaj Yes, as you guessed the field exists, I wanted to skip irrelevant stuff and make the code examples as brief as possible. In the end it was something much simpler: the report I was checking was looked up via mongoose directly instead of through my API which is why it wasnt populated..... Thank you very much for your time though, I actually found the mistake while doing what you said

Comment: @CyborgFish Please post an answer of the issue has been detected.

Comment: @ZeMoon Nice call, I will as soon as I get home, in case it helps someone, but as I said it was just a silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was a simple mistake: the report I was checking was looked up via mongoose directly instead of through my API which is why it wasnt populated. The correct code would be:

```
Report.findOne title: 'test', (err, report) ->
      return done(err) if err
      request(app).put("#{apiUrl}/#{report._id}/vote").set("Authorization", "Bearer testKey").end (err, res) ->
        return done(err) if err
        expect(res.statusCode).toBe 200
        request(app).get("#{apiUrl}/#{report._id}").set("Authorization", "Bearer testKey").end (err, res) ->
          report = res.body
          expect(report.votes?.length).toBe 1
          expect(report.votes[0]?.texto).toEqual ''
          expect(report.votos[0]?.user?.name).toEqual 'test'
          done()
```

The API report lookup with populate was working properly